# Permenantly deleting Anaconda and Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, uninstallation

If you uninstall Anaconda through the control panel > Uninstall method, will Jupyter notebook also be deleted?

Comment: Yes. The Jupyter notebook is part of the Anaconda installation, so should be removed when uninstalling Anaconda.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The reason I ask is that I installed the Jupyter notebook separately. I also wondered, where does the data go when things are saved in the Jupyter notebook and why does the interface list all the folders on the PC?

Comment: The side condition you mention in your comment should actually be n the question as it is an important restriction and it should be noted whether or not Jupyter should be uninstalled or not.

Comment: In English please?

Comment: Jupyter notebook is a Python module and should also be removed when uninstalling Anaconda. However, it will not remove the notebook files (.ipynb) itself. These will have to be deleted manually.

Comment: Thank you, how do I do this and where are they saved?

Comment: Unfortunately the Jupyter notebooks could be saved anywhere. If you didn't make a conscious decision where to save them, they are probably stored in the directory you used to start Jupyter notebook.  If you are on Windows, the most likely candidate is `C:\users\<your user name>`

Comment: Do you know how the notebooks are shared?